# Menu and Title bars have disappeared

Tags: menu, menu-bar

My menu and title bars have disappeared. All was well until I started my HP Probook 4520s this morning. I can get to settings by right-clicking on the desktop and all seems well. I have installed updates via the command line but I can't get to any applications. Ubuntu 15.04 64 bit. Please help!

Comment: Can you make a screenshot?

Comment: I found an answer. I installed Compiz Config Settings Manager and ran ccsm. I then enabled the Unity plugin. This seems like a bug to me. I tried posting this in the "answer" but apparently I'm not allowed to.

Comment: @stroudmw you have to wait a but until it lets you I think. Come back later :) also, you could break the menu bars again (reproduce the bug) and then report a bug with `ubuntu-bug ccsm` while it's broken so ubuntu-bug can grab the logs while it's broken and then state in the bug description how to reproduce the bug :)